# Visual Basic Win32_VideoController Pulls Wrong Graphics Card

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

First, Thanks for all the help! Second, as my title states above, I am using Visual Basic (not C#) that I am trying to pull my graphics card information. Now I am on a laptop that has Intel Integrated Graphics and a NVIDIA GTX1060. I have my NVIDIA card as the card that is being used. However, the VB (see code below) pulls the Intel graphics info. Can I make it so that I can get it to pull my NVIDIA card? Thanks again!

```
Dim search4 As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HAH! Figured it out a minute later..... Dumb me.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController Where AdapterCompatibility='NVIDIA'
```

This will pull the Nvidia card. It actually was just jumping to the integrated for reasons unknown to me, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this, if you need both gpu hardware info.

```
"Select * from Win32_VideoController where deviceid = 'videocontroller1'"

"Select * from Win32_VideoController where deviceid = 'videocontroller2'"
```